# JSON Parameter Config Groovy Script not working

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to create a "Extended choice config" parameter. I am putting my code in "JSON Parameter Config Groovy Script", but I cannot see it in "build with parameters" screen. I tried with both, regular json and org.boon and got the same [no] results.

[image: This is what I choices I selected]

[image: in "Build with parameters" I am getting]

the code I used (for org.boon) is the same that can be found on: https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=92736450

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your config groovy script with the below code and it will work. The JSON Parameter feature for the Extended Choice Parameter is based on the https://github.com/json-editor/json-editor

The groovy script should return a JSON object that corresponds to the "options" object referred to in json-editor.

***UPDATE***

Ensure that your Extended name choice parameter "Name" doesnt have space. So in your case change the name from "Testing Json" to "testing_json" or Json (string without space) and it will work.

```
    import net.sf.json.JSONObject

def jsonEditorOptions = JSONObject.fromObject(/{
        disable_edit_json: true,
        disable_properties: true,
        no_additional_properties: true,
        disable_collapse: true,
        disable_array_add: true,
        disable_array_delete: true,
        disable_array_reorder: true,
        theme: "bootstrap2",
        iconlib:"fontawesome4",
        schema: {
          "type": "object",
          "title": "Name",
          "properties": {
            "first_name": {
              "type": "string",
              "propertyOrder" : 1
            },
            "last_name": {
              "type": "string",
              "propertyOrder" : 2
            },
            "full_name": {
              "type": "string",
              "propertyOrder" : 3,
              "template": "{{fname}} {{lname}}",
              "watch": {
                "fname": "first_name",
                "lname": "last_name"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        startval: {
            "first_name" : "John",
            "last_name" : "Doe",
            "full_name" : "John Doe"
        }
}/);
```

Comment: Thank you **Isaiah4110**, but I am still getting the same results

Comment: what version of extended choice plugin and jenkins are you on?

Comment: I'm on version: 0.82

Comment: After saving the script - when you clicked on build with parameters for the job. Did you get the script approval message?

You have unapproved groovy scripts that need approval before they can be executed. Go to In-Process Script Approval page to approve your scripts.

Comment: Ensure that your Extended name choice parameter "Name" doesnt have space. So in your case change the name from "Testing Json" to testing_json or testing (without spaces) and it will work.

Comment: After 16 years in computers, I miss a stupid mistake like that. I am embarrassed. 
Thank you for your help, this solved my problem